# Realsense SDK 2.0 installation in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, realsense

I have installed Realsense SDK on WSL2 (Windows 11) and it works fine but there is a problem related with some permissions.

I have followed this guide:
https://robots.uc3m.es/installation-guides/install-realsense2.html

All is fine except, realsense-viewer command doesn't work properly without `sudo` .

I receive this error:

```
03/02 12:26:45,534 ERROR [140206850172672] (handle-libusb.h:51) failed to open usb interface: 0, error: RS2_USB_STATUS_ACCESS
```

03/02 12:26:45,600 ERROR [140207016855296] (sensor.cpp:664) acquire_power failed: failed to set power state

If I use sudo with realsense-viewer command, this works fine.

I have checked sudo 99-realsense-libusb.rules but the permissions are fine (all 0666 or 0777). The usb configuration uses usbipd from PowerShell and the attach is done by:

```
usbipd wsl attach --busid <busid>
```

The real problem is that i can't use the camera with ROS2 because I can't execute ROS2 with sudo, and the normal way to do this sends to me the same error I wrote some lines before.

What is wrong with this?

THank you so much.

Update:

If I try rs-enumerate-devices without sudo, I receive the same error.

If I use lsusb, RealSense device is appears as device connected.